# Usar el resultado de una consulta como una variables para un INSERT en PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Estoy intentando usar el resultado de una consulta como un simple valor para agregarlo en un insert de la siguiente manera:

```
$query = "select max(idInventario) from inventarios;";
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
$ID_inv = $row[0];

$sql = "insert into inventariosproductos 
            idInventario = '$ID_inv',
            idProducto= '$_REQUEST[productos]',
            cantidad = '$_REQUEST[cantidad]'";
```

Dandome el siguiente error:

```
Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result
```

Cual seria la forma correcta de hacerlo?

Comment: mismo error `Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$ID_inv vendria siendo el Query, debes recuperar el array de resultados de ese Query para utilizarlo en otra consutla.

Ejemplo, suponiendo que la columna que quieres utilizar se llama "id_inventario":

```
$query = "select max(idInventario) from inventarios";
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
$ID_inv = $row["id_inventario"];
```

Ahora puedes utilizar $ID_inv en otra consulta.

Comment: Haciendo eso obtengo el siguiente error: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_fetch_array()`

Comment: @Xultron ese error va a depender de que driver usas para conectarte: `mysqli` o `PDO` trata de checar ese punto o agregarlo a tu pregunta, lo que pasa que el driver mysql y todas sus funciones fueron removidas desde PHP 7

Comment: Prueba con mysqli_fetch_array()

Comment: Acabo de revisar y si uso el driver mysql, sin embargo ahora obtengo este error   `mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysql` teniendo mi codigo de esta forma  `$query = "select max(idInventario) from inventarios;";
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
$ID_inv = $row[0];`, perdon si tengo errores muy tontos, soy nuevo en php.

Comment: Te pondré un código de ejemplo que estoy utilizando:

`$sql = "SELECT user  FROM login WHERE id = 1";
if($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
      $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
      // aqui continúa el código con las filas devueltas por $row`

Si te fijas usé la función mysqli_query($conn, $sql) donde $conn es la conexión a MySQL que ya hice con anterioridad, y $sql la consulta.

Comment: Muchas Gracias! Me sirvió ^^.